# MVC5 website - internationalization of views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been following multiple tutorials (such as [this one](http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/)) and I am able to build a multilanguage ASP.NET website through resource (.resx) files.

The thing is, that is nice for words or phrases... but what if you have a View with multiple paragraphs of hundreds of words? How do you manage that? My feeling is that the key-value translation of the .resx file seems rather inefficient in this case.

I've been doing a lot of research trying to solve that, with no success so far. The closest I've gotten has been [this post](http://www.pbworks.net/multilanguage-mvc4-website/) (which even provides the .zip with all the code), but unfortunately it is based on MVC4 (not 5) and I was not able to translate it to MVC5. But it uses a brilliant solution to solve the "I want this view rendered in this language" problem: add a suffix `ViewName.fr.cshtml` so the view is automatically redirected to the correct language. This is the code for that, and this is where I got stuck in MVC5:

```
public class LocalizedViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView (ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
    {
        List<string> searched = new List<string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partialViewName))
        {
            ViewEngineResult result;

            result = base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, string.Format("{0}.{1}", partialViewName, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name), useCache);

            if (result.View != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            searched.AddRange(result.SearchedLocations);

            result = base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, string.Format("{0}.{1}", partialViewName, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName), useCache);

            if (result.View != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            searched.AddRange(result.SearchedLocations);
        }

        return new ViewEngineResult(searched.Distinct().ToList());
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView (ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        List<string> searched = new List<string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            ViewEngineResult result;

            result = base.FindView(controllerContext, string.Format("{0}.{1}", viewName, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name), masterName, useCache);

            if (result.View != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            searched.AddRange(result.SearchedLocations);

            result = base.FindView(controllerContext, string.Format("{0}.{1}", viewName, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName), masterName, useCache);

            if (result.View != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            searched.AddRange(result.SearchedLocations);
        }

        return new ViewEngineResult(searched.Distinct().ToList());
    }
}
```

It is not that I want to make this particular code work but I want to find a solution to the "show the view in a particular language" problem.

Comment: That's in fact the code you could use to solve your problem. What exactly are you stuck at?

Comment: @ViktorA My problem is that the runtime never reaches this part of the code (as opposed to the original MVC4 project I was trying to imitate). I did not find any references through "find all references" in (either in my MVC5 project and in the source MVC4) so I guessed that it was a change of behavior between MVC5 and MVC4, which could of course be a wrong conclusion but I am not able to move further in my research.

Comment: @ViktorA So I got a little deeper into how I could specify a custom location to “search for views” in ASP.NET, and I saw that I was missing the line `ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, new LocalizedViewEngine());` in the `Application_Start()` of `Global.asax.cs`. However I sense that there should be an easier way to create heavy-content multilingual views in ASP.